# "Raspyness" vs "raspy-ness"

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

If I'm talking about someone's voice is *raspyness* or *raspy-ness* correct?

> The **raspyness** of Cobain’s voice adds another layer of complexity to the song.
>
> The **raspy-ness** of Cobain’s voice adds another layer of complexity to the song.

Spelling checker doesn't like *raspyness*, but *raspy-ness* doesn't look quite right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper term you're looking for is *raspiness*. Definitely not raspy-ness, neither raspyness, nor raspi-ness. The Wiktionary [lists it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raspiness), even with quotations backing it up:

> The speaking voice was clear and strong with no raspiness, but there was a noticeable rasp in the loud singing voice.
>
> > ~ *1978, Mavis Douglas, Vocal problems of the young singer*

Answer (score 0):

If it is a word it would be spelt *raspiness* but I'm not sure it is a word. Wiktionary has [an entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raspiness) for it at least.

If it were not actually a dictionary word then *raspy-ness* as a made up word would be acceptable in casual text.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular instance,

> "the *rasp* of Cobain's voice [...]"

could be an acceptable alternative, where *rasp* means the harsh sound in question; however, the meaning is subtly changed from referring to the rasping *quality* of his voice to the rasping *sound* of his voice.